# USB Driver for HTC Dream G1 - 64 bit Windows 7

Tags: usb, windows, 1.5-cupcake, usb-drivers

I have a HTC Dream G1 (T-Mobile) - android version 1.5 and I have 64 bit Windows 7 on my laptop. I am unable to access the memory card in my phone through my laptop. Can someone tell me how to install the USB driver for my phone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go and download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) installer.
2. When the SDK setup tool runs, you can select the [USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
3. The drivers will be in <install_directory>extras\google\usb_driver
4. find the android_winusb.inf and right click it
5. click install

if right click -> install doesn't work, then try the following

1. Start Menu -> Right Click Computer -> Click Properties
2. Click Device Manager (on the left)
3. Find the device in the hardware list, will probably have a "warning icon"
4. Right click the item and select Update Driver Software
5. Select Browse my computer for driver software
6. Select the usb driver directory noted above
7. Check Include subfolders
8. Click next
9. finished...

your device should now have usable drivers so you can mount the sdcard.

For reference, the android sdk documents also has a [page with links](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html) to many of the different OEM drivers too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both the methods you suggested, and they do not work. Can you suggest any other solution?

Comment: if you already have drivers installed, uninstall them first.

Comment: I installed Android ADB interface, Android Bootloader Interface, and Android Composite ADB Interface - all 3 drivers, but still it doesnt work :(

Comment: once you have the drivers installed, open a command line and navigate to the SDK directory. then navigate in to the platform-tools directory, so your command line should look something like: C:\android-sdk\platform-tools. now type: "adb devices", no quotes. does it return anything?

Comment: It says list of devices, and the next line is blank. No devices are listed.

Comment: your driver is not installed correctly. uninstall all the android devices, then try to reinstall.

Comment: Tried again. It did not work. Note that I added the drivers as a legacy device, as direct installation of the drivers did not work

Answer (score -3):

just follow these directions to install the android driver... very easy ! how to install [Android driver](http://www.androidsim.net/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html)

Comment: Answers that send readers off to other sites are generally not considered useful.